# Will the code below clearInterval be executed inside setInterval?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

```
var myvar = setInterval (function(){
    if (true) {
       clearInterval(myvar);
    }
    alert('333');
},1000);
```

As far as I see the `alert('333');` will appear exactly one time upon execution of the code above (you can test it in the console).
Am I right?

What's the most proper way to exclude executing this alert so nothing is executed below `if`, when the statement inside `if` is true.

Comment: Downvoter please explain your vote or provide your best solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I see the alert('333'); will appear exactly one time upon execution of the code above (you can test it in the console). Am I right?

Yes, you're right. The first call to the callback clears the interval, and then the code continues and does the `alert`. There will be no subsequent calls to the callback.

> What's the most proper way to exclude executing this alert so nothing is executed below if, when the statement inside if is `true`.

Either use `else` or `return`.

`else`:

```
var myvar = setInterval (function(){
    if (true) {
       clearInterval(myvar);
    } else {
       alert('333');
    }
},1000);
```

`return`:

```
var myvar = setInterval (function(){
    if (true) {
       clearInterval(myvar);
       return;
    }
    alert('333');
},1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

> What's the most proper way to exclude executing this alert so nothing is executed below if

Use `return`.

```
var myfunc = setInterval (function(){
    if (true) {
       clearInterval(myfunc);
       return;//now no further code will run
    }
    alert('333');
},1000);
```